# Service Fabric Reliability on Standalone Cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am running Service Fabric across a three node standalone cluster.  Each cluster is on a separate virtual machine in a corporate enterprise cloud environment.  Recently two of my virtual machines on which the nodes reside where deleted (one of the deleted machines being the machine which the cluster was created from).  After this deletion, I attempted access Service Fabric Explorer on the remaining machine only to get a "Page Cannot be found" error.  Furthermore, the `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` (for attempting to connect to the remaining node) and the `Get-ServiceFabricApplication` Powershell commands fail stating:

> "A communication error caused the operation to fail."

and

> "No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is a connectivity/firewall/DNS issue."

respectively.

Under what conditions does Service Fabric's automatic failover capability work on a standalone cluster?  Are there any steps that can be taken so that I would still be able to access Service Fabric from the remaining node(s) on a standalone cluster if several nodes suddenly go down at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cluster services run as stateful services on the cluster. For a stateful service you need a minimum number of nodes running, to guarantee its availability and ability to preserve state. The minimum number of nodes is equal to the target replica set count of the partition/service.

If less than the minimum number of nodes are available, your (cluster) services will stop working.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server).

> The cluster size is determined by your business needs.  However, you
>   must have a minimum cluster size of three nodes  (machines or virtual
>   machines).